# Thesis Table of Contents in Parts

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, thesis

I am writing my thesis. I have completed all the chapters and other related stuff (e.g., List of Figures, etc.) similar to the other standard theses. But, now I want to break these chapters into "Parts" similar as shown in the attached picture (color is not needed). Also, there should not be an empty page in the writeup for these parts. Please help me.

The picture is the screenshot of the Chicago manual of style online (the link below):
https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/frontmatter/toc.html

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You could make use of `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part title}`. For a more specific answer, please prepare a small example document that shows the documentclass you use and some example chapters.

Comment: The page number is showing in front of the PARTS and I don't want it. Also, it is adding the Parts content in the wrong place. For example: if I have 

\include{Ch1/chapter1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{PART I: First Part} 
 \include{Ch2/chapter2} 
\include{Ch3/chapter3} 
\include{Ch4/chapter4} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{PART II: Second Part} 
\include{Ch5/chapter5} 
\include{Ch6/conclusions} 
then, PART I is appearing after chapter 2 in the list of contents and similarly Part II after chapter 5.